# Special Price With Configurable And Simple Products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, special-price

I am adding a configurable product with some associated products.

In that configurable product I am entering both special price and old price. In that configurable product i have 4 associated product. But the thing is that 3 associated products have both special price and old price, and one contains only old price.

The result I am getting is that all associated products have both special price and old price.

But this result is wrong because 3 products have both special price and old price and one product have only old price.

How it that possible?

Comment: `Can you give example of configurable product ? It's not clear to me what the problem is`. behalf of Henk Valk

Answer (score 4):

Magento completely ignores prices of associated products in the configurable product type. You can specify a price difference for each associated product within a configurable product, but the base price and special prices are always taken from the configurable product itself.

Conclusion is: You cannot achieve what you try to do without custom extensions. There are some extensions around that change how pricing for configurable products work, but due to these substantial changes there are always rewrites of important core classes and you should think twice if you really need it.

This extension is a good example: [Better Configurable Products](http://de.nr-apps.com/store/bcp-better-configurable-products.html)

But you should not expect it to work out of the box, at least not if you use a custom theme. This is not a "one click install and forget" extension, it should be installed and configured by a developer.